# The Intent of the FirebaseUI is destroyed with the onBackPressed () method, how to prevent from destroying?

Tags: android, authentication, kotlin, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

my problem is that I use 2 activities,
but this problem focuses on the first activity, the A
this activity is blank ok.
I'm using FirebaseUI, when I start the App,
shows me the login options,
This is generated by the Auth.getInstance () intent
ok I show you the code of the method.

```
private fun authenticateUser() {
    startActivityForResult(
        AuthUI.getInstance()
            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setTheme(R.style.CustomTheme)
            .setLogo(R.drawable.firelogo)
            .setAvailableProviders(getProviderList())
            .setIsSmartLockEnabled(true)
            .build(),
        REQUEST_CODE)
}
```

when I press onBackPressed (),
this method destroys the attempt generated by FirebaseUI,
and it shows me activity A, which is blank,
If I press "Back" again, it shows me again
the intent of FirebaseUI. okay

I want to avoid pressing "Back" when I'm on the FirebaseUI screen

I do not know if you understand the problem that I have.

There are 2 images, the first one is generated by FirebaseUI,
the second is activity A, which is blank.
If I press "Back" I see activity A, blank,
if I press again, it generates the activity of FirebaseUI

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mWIX.jpg

the onBackPressed() method I have it like this

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if(currentUser == null) {
        authenticateUser()
    }
}
```

The problem is, I do not know how to prevent it from being destroyed
the activity generated by FirebaseUI. caused by the onBackPressed() method. This activity is generated by the Intent
AuthUI.getInstance()....

```
startActivityForResult(
    AuthUI.getInstance()
        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
        .setTheme (R.style.CustomTheme)
        .setLogo (R.drawable.firelogo)
        .setAvailableProviders(getProviderList())
        .setIsSmartLockEnabled(true)
        .build(),
    REQUEST_CODE)
```

Comment: Where are you starting the auth ui? Inside A?

Comment: Yes, it is inside activity A, https://imgur.com/a/fKleL

Comment: btw do not use the fire logo, they cansue you for using a logo which isn't their official logo..  looking into the rest to figure out your issue

Comment: It's okay, I'll change the logo

Answer (score 1):

Well, answering my question.
This has to do with the life cycle of the activity,
so what I did was:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        onRestart()
}

override fun onRestart() {
    currentUser = null
    if (currentUser == null) {
        startActivity(Intent(this, FirebaseAuthActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    }
    super.onRestart()
}
```